# quickAdd events in X days from now

Tags: google-calendar, if-this-then-that

IFTTT recipe: if I send an email to the IFTTT trigger address tagged `#m`, quickAdd event to Google Calendar.

Since it would be a cycle reminder, I want to add an event in 28 days.  quickAdd does not accept add events *from* the day sent until 28 days later.

I tried `in 28 days`, `28 days from today`, `4 weeks`, `4 weeks from now` but in every case either the `from` or `in` is input as text.

Can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

*(not an actual solution, just evidence that it might not be possible)*

---

The Google Calendar channel on IFTTT uses Google's "Quick Add" feature, which you can also play with directly in the web app (top-left corner).

[This help page](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/72143) (under "Create an event using quick add") gives some tips and says that "today", "tomorrow", or a "day or week" will work - but it makes no mention of "next month", "in X weeks" or "in X days". In my testing, I also couldn't find one that works.